# Error loading zone 'europe-west1-a': googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/google-project-id/zones/europe-west1-a' was not found, notFound

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Having this error and it is driving me crazy.... I can't get it to create more than 1 VM with a static IP.

Here is my main.tf

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("terraform-key.json")
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "my-bucket"
    prefix = "terraform"
    credentials = "terraform-key.json"
   }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "new-terraform-network"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "prod-cluster"
  location = var.zone
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  name       = "pool-1"
  location   = var.zone
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = 3

  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
    disk_size_gb = 10
    disk_type = "pd-standard"


    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]
  }
}
resource "google_compute_address" "vm-host"{
  count =  var.vm-host-number
  region  =  var.vm-host-region
  name  = "vm-host-${count.index}"
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "vm-host" {
  name         = "vm-host-${count.index}"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "europe-west1-a"
  count        =  var.vm-host-number

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
    access_config {
        nat_ip = "google_compute_address.vm-host-${count.index}.address"
    }
  }
}
```

My variable file

```
variable "project" {
  default = "my-project"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "us-central1"
}

variable "zone"  {
  default = "us-central1-c"
}

variable "cidr_ip" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "vm-host-number"{
  default = "2"
}

variable "vm-host-region"{
   default = "us-central1"
}
variable  "vm-host-zone"{
   default = "europe-west1-a"
}
```

The error -

```
Error: Error loading zone 'europe-west1-a': googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/GoogleProjectID/zones/europe-west1-a' was not found, notFound

  on main.tf line 65, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm-host":
  65: resource "google_compute_instance" "vm-host" {
```

Cant understand why it won't create the VMs, If i try the same to just create 1 VM, without the variables/count it works fine ><.  I mean the zone definitely exists...

Edit -

Next issue is I can't create a static IP for each VM.

```
resource "google_compute_address" "vm-host" {
  count =  var.vm-host-number
  #region  =  var-vm-host-region
   region = "us-central1-a"
   name  = "vm-host-${count.index}"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm-host-vms" {
  name         = "vm-host-${count.index}"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"
  count        =  var.vm-host-number

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
    access_config {
        nat_ip = "google_compute_address.vm-host-${count.index}.address"
    }
  }
}
```

The nat_ip = "google_compute_address.vm-host-${count.index}.address"  line needs to be  google_compute_address.resourcename.address however,

I've tried -

```
resource "google_compute_address" "vm-host-${count.index}" {
  count =  var.vm-host-number
   region = "us-central1-a"
   name  = "vm-host-${count.index}"
}



resource "google_compute_address" "vm-host-$${count.index}" {
  count =  var.vm-host-number

   region = "us-central1-a"
   name  = vm-host-${count.index}"
}
```

But whatever i do, it just won't work.  Is there some special syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

A zone "europe-west1-a" does not exist.

You can get a list of existing zones using the command `gcloud compute zones list`:

```
CloudShell:$ gcloud compute zones list --filter=region=europe-west1
NAME            REGION        STATUS
europe-west1-b  europe-west1  UP
europe-west1-d  europe-west1  UP
europe-west1-c  europe-west1  UP
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah i've since figured that out - struggling now to get Public static address to be create where the resource name  increments with count.